# Prove $(X_n)n≥1$, $X_n \sim Exp(n)$ converges in distribution to $0$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Prove $(X_n)n≥1$,  $X_n \sim Exp(n)$ converges in distribution to $0$ using the following property:

$X_n \to X$ in distribution $\iff F_{X_n}(x)\to F_X(x) \forall$ continuity points of $F_X$

**My attempt**

If $x<0,  F_{X_n}(x)=0 \to 0,$ as $n\to +\infty$

If $x\ge0,  F_{X_n}(x)=1-e^{-nx} \to 1$ as $n\to +\infty$

**From these results how can I identify I am getting the cumulative distribution function of a constant 0? It looks that I got a step function at 0. What is the cumulative distribution function of a constat random variable  to start with? It doesn't even have much of "random".**

Note: I know I can use a stronger convergence to imply the result but the exercise asks to use this property explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is  the constant random variable $c$ then $F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)=1$ if $ x \geq c$ and $0$ if $x<c$ (simply because the empty set has probability $0$ and the sample space $\Omega$ has probability $1$). Taking $c=0$ we see that $F_{X_n}(x) \to F_X(x)$ for $x>0$ as well as $x<0$. Convergence in distribution requires convergence only at points of continuity of the limit function, so convergence at $0$ is not required.

Comment: I liked the remark in parentheses, that clarifies it a lot. So a constant random variable can't be classified as absolutely continuous because there is no density, then what would it be? discrete? continuous?

Comment: @mathlover It is discrete. Any r.v. which assumes at most countable number of values is discrete.